# numbers coming up with my quick search results? CE 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, search, search-terms

When I type in a search item in the search box on my store I keep having numbers coming up next to my quick search results?

[image: Numbers with my search results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the number of results this search term matches (at least the last time it was used). If you don't wish the numbers to be visible the simplest solution will probably be to hide them with css. By default it's in a span with the class `amount`, so this should be fairly easy.